# Getting multiple errors in kotlin class in android?

Tags: android, kotlin

I am developing an android app using Kotlin but I am getting following errors

```
C:\Users\admin\Desktop\masters\app\src\main\java\com\empowered\healo\ui\screens\therapy\TherapySettingsFragment.kt: (118, 9): Function invocation 'levelUp(...)' expected
e: C:\Users\admin\Desktop\masters\app\src\main\java\com\empowered\healo\ui\screens\therapy\TherapySettingsFragment.kt: (118, 9): No value passed for parameter 'therapyPackage'
e: C:\Users\admin\Desktop\masters\app\src\main\java\com\empowered\healo\ui\screens\therapy\TherapySettingsFragment.kt: (118, 17): Unresolved reference: setOnClickListener
e: C:\Users\admin\Desktop\masters\app\src\main\java\com\empowered\healo\ui\screens\therapy\TherapySettingsFragment.kt: (123, 9): Function invocation 'levelDown(...)' expected
e: C:\Users\admin\Desktop\masters\app\src\main\java\com\empowered\healo\ui\screens\therapy\TherapySettingsFragment.kt: (123, 9): No value passed for parameter 'therapyPackage'
e: C:\Users\admin\Desktop\masters\app\src\main\java\com\empowered\healo\ui\screens\therapy\TherapySettingsFragment.kt: (123, 19): Unresolved reference: setOnClickListener
e: C:\Users\admin\Desktop\masters\app\src\main\java\com\empowered\healo\ui\screens\therapy\TherapySettingsFragment.kt: (146, 17): Function invocation 'levelDown(...)' expected
e: C:\Users\admin\Desktop\masters\app\src\main\java\com\empowered\healo\ui\screens\therapy\TherapySettingsFragment.kt: (146, 17): No value passed for parameter 'therapyPackage'
e: C:\Users\admin\Desktop\masters\app\src\main\java\com\empowered\healo\ui\screens\therapy\TherapySettingsFragment.kt: (146, 27): Unresolved reference: isEnabled
e: C:\Users\admin\Desktop\masters\app\src\main\java\com\empowered\healo\ui\screens\therapy\TherapySettingsFragment.kt: (147, 17): Function invocation 'levelDown(...)' expected
e: C:\Users\admin\Desktop\masters\app\src\main\java\com\empowered\healo\ui\screens\therapy\TherapySettingsFragment.kt: (147, 17): No value passed for parameter 'therapyPackage'
e: C:\Users\admin\Desktop\masters\app\src\main\java\com\empowered\healo\ui\screens\therapy\TherapySettingsFragment.kt: (147, 27): Unresolved reference: alpha
e: C:\Users\admin\Desktop\masters\app\src\main\java\com\empowered\healo\ui\screens\therapy\TherapySettingsFragment.kt: (149, 17): Function invocation 'levelDown(...)' expected
e: C:\Users\admin\Desktop\masters\app\src\main\java\com\empowered\healo\ui\screens\therapy\TherapySettingsFragment.kt: (149, 17): No value passed for parameter 'therapyPackage'
e: C:\Users\admin\Desktop\masters\app\src\main\java\com\empowered\healo\ui\screens\therapy\TherapySettingsFragment.kt: (149, 27): Unresolved reference: isEnabled
e: C:\Users\admin\Desktop\masters\app\src\main\java\com\empowered\healo\ui\screens\therapy\TherapySettingsFragment.kt: (150, 17): Function invocation 'levelDown(...)' expected
e: C:\Users\admin\Desktop\masters\app\src\main\java\com\empowered\healo\ui\screens\therapy\TherapySettingsFragment.kt: (150, 17): No value passed for parameter 'therapyPackage'
e: C:\Users\admin\Desktop\masters\app\src\main\java\com\empowered\healo\ui\screens\therapy\TherapySettingsFragment.kt: (150, 27): Unresolved reference: alpha
e: C:\Users\admin\Desktop\masters\app\src\main\java\com\empowered\healo\ui\screens\therapy\TherapySettingsFragment.kt: (153, 13): Function invocation 'levelDown(...)' expected
e: C:\Users\admin\Desktop\masters\app\src\main\java\com\empowered\healo\ui\screens\therapy\TherapySettingsFragment.kt: (153, 13): No value passed for parameter 'therapyPackage'
e: C:\Users\admin\Desktop\masters\app\src\main\java\com\empowered\healo\ui\screens\therapy\TherapySettingsFragment.kt: (153, 23): Unresolved reference: isEnabled
e: C:\Users\admin\Desktop\masters\app\src\main\java\com\empowered\healo\ui\screens\therapy\TherapySettingsFragment.kt: (154, 13): Function invocation 'levelDown(...)' expected
e: C:\Users\admin\Desktop\masters\app\src\main\java\com\empowered\healo\ui\screens\therapy\TherapySettingsFragment.kt: (154, 13): No value passed for parameter 'therapyPackage'
e: C:\Users\admin\Desktop\masters\app\src\main\java\com\empowered\healo\ui\screens\therapy\TherapySettingsFragment.kt: (154, 23): Unresolved reference: alpha
```

below my TherapySettingsFragment.kt file

```
class TherapySettingsFragment : BaseMvpFragment(), TherapySettingView {


    private var data = emptyList<TherapyPackage>()
    private var presenter = TherapySettingsPresenter(this)
    private var time = 0
    private var currentItem: TherapyPackage? = null

    override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
        rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_therapy_settings, container, false)
        return rootView
    }

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
        toolbar.setOnNavigateIconClickListener { router.exit() }
        toolbar.setOnToolIconClickListener { openNavDrawer() }
        viewPager.adapter = object : PagerAdapter() {
            override fun isViewFromObject(view: View, `object`: Any): Boolean {
                return view == `object`
            }

            override fun destroyItem(container: ViewGroup, position: Int, `object`: Any) {
                container.removeView(`object` as RelativeLayout?)
            }

            @RequiresApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
            override fun instantiateItem(container: ViewGroup, position: Int): Any {
                val contentView = RelativeLayout(container.context)
                contentView.layoutParams = ViewGroup.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT)
                val text = TextView(container.context)
                val item = data[position]
                text.text = getString(R.string.level_title, item.title?.getText, item.activeTherapyPackageLevel?.levelName?.getText)
                text.typeface = context?.let { ResourcesCompat.getFont(it, R.font.grotesk_light) }
                text.textSize = 26f
                text.letterSpacing = 0.06f
                text.setLineSpacing(1.2f, 1.15f)
                text.gravity = Gravity.CENTER
                text.setTextColor(Color.WHITE)


                val params = RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT)
                params.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_IN_PARENT, RelativeLayout.TRUE)

                contentView.addView(text, params)
                container.addView(contentView)

                return contentView
            }

            override fun getItemPosition(`object`: Any): Int {
                return POSITION_NONE
            }

            override fun getCount(): Int =
                    data.count()

        }
        presenter.getPackages()
        presenter.getDuration()
        timer.text = time.toString()
        decTime.setOnClickListener {
            if (time > 0) {
                time--
                timer.text = time.toString()
            }
        }
        incTime.setOnClickListener {
            if (time < 60) {
                time++
                timer.text = time.toString()
            }
        }
        viewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(object : ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener {
            override fun onPageScrollStateChanged(state: Int) {

            }

            override fun onPageScrolled(position: Int, positionOffset: Float, positionOffsetPixels: Int) {

            }

            override fun onPageSelected(position: Int) {
                currentItem = data[position]
                checkArrowState(position)

            }

        })
        levelUp().setOnClickListener {
            if (currentItem != null)
                presenter.checkLevelUp(currentItem!!)
        }

        levelDown.setOnClickListener {
            if (currentItem != null)
                presenter.packageLevelDown(currentItem!!)
        }

        checkArrowState(0)

        rightBtn.setOnClickListener { viewPager.currentItem = viewPager.currentItem + 1 }
        leftBtn.setOnClickListener { viewPager.currentItem = viewPager.currentItem - 1 }
    }

    private fun checkArrowState(currentPosition: Int) {
        if (data.size > 1) {
            rightBtn.visibility = if (currentPosition == data.size - 1) View.GONE else View.VISIBLE
            leftBtn.visibility = if (currentPosition == 0) View.GONE else View.VISIBLE
        }
        initLevelState(currentItem)

    }

    private fun initLevelState(currentItem: TherapyPackage?) {
        if (currentItem!!.therapyLevels.size >= 2) {
            if (currentItem.activeTherapyPackageLevelId == currentItem.therapyLevels.minBy { it.id }?.id) {
                levelDown.isEnabled = false
                levelDown.alpha = 0.8f
            } else {
                levelDown.isEnabled = true
                levelDown.alpha = 1f
            }
        } else {
            levelDown.isEnabled = false
            levelDown.alpha = 0.8f
        }
    }

    override fun setData(data: List<TherapyPackage>) {
        this.data = data
        if (data.isNotEmpty())
            currentItem = if (currentItem != null) {
                data.firstOrNull { it.therapyPackageId == currentItem?.therapyPackageId }
                        ?: data.first()
            } else {
                data.first()
            }
        viewPager.adapter?.notifyDataSetChanged()
        currentItem?.let { initLevelState(currentItem) }
    }

    override fun setExerciseTime(sec: Int) {
        time = sec
        timer.text = sec.toString()
    }

    override fun getExerciseTime(): Int {
        return time
    }


    override fun onDestroyView() {
        super.onDestroyView()
        presenter.saveTime()
    }

    override fun moveToScreen(screen: String, data: Bundle) {
        router.newRootScreen(screen, data)
    }

    override fun startLevelUp(therapyPackage: TherapyPackage) {
        startActivityForResult(Intent(context, DiagnosticActivity::class.java).putExtra(DiagnosticActivity.ACTION, ACTION_LEVEL_UP).putExtra(ACTION_LEVEL_UP, therapyPackage.therapyPackageId), DiagnosticActivity.REQUEST_CODE)
    }

    override fun showLevelUpDialog(therapyPackage: TherapyPackage, confirm: Boolean) {
        CustomAlertDialogBuilder(context)
                .setTitle(R.string.therapy_improvement)
                .setBackground(R.drawable.dialog_white_background)
                .setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#0000ff"))
                .addMessage(if (confirm) getString(R.string.start_level_up, therapyPackage.title?.getText)
                else getString(R.string.level_up_message_not_confirmed))
                .setPositiveButton(if (confirm) R.string.progress_action_yes else R.string.positive_not_confirm_level_up, object : CustomAlertDialogBuilder.OnItemDialogClickListener {
                    override fun onClick(dialog: CustomAlertDialogBuilder.CustomDialogInterface) {
                        presenter.startLevelUp(therapyPackage)
                        dialog.dismiss()
                    }

                })
                .setNegativeButton(if (confirm) R.string.no else R.string.negative_not_confirm_level_up, object : CustomAlertDialogBuilder.OnItemDialogClickListener {
                    override fun onClick(dialog: CustomAlertDialogBuilder.CustomDialogInterface) {
                        dialog.dismiss()
                    }
                }).build()?.show()
    }

    override fun levelDown(therapyPackage: TherapyPackage) {
        showMessage(getString(R.string.level_down, therapyPackage.title?.getText))
    }

    override fun levelUp(therapyPackage: TherapyPackage) {
        showMessage(getString(R.string.level_up, therapyPackage.title?.getText))
    }

    override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)
        presenter.getPackages()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

in your code you are using levelDown as an object with properties:

```
    private fun initLevelState(currentItem: TherapyPackage?) {
    if (currentItem!!.therapyLevels.size >= 2) {
        if (currentItem.activeTherapyPackageLevelId == currentItem.therapyLevels.minBy { it.id }?.id) {
            levelDown.isEnabled = false
            levelDown.alpha = 0.8f
        } else {
            levelDown.isEnabled = true
            levelDown.alpha = 1f
        }
    } else {
        levelDown.isEnabled = false
        levelDown.alpha = 0.8f
    }
}
```

but you are declaring it as an overriden function:

```
override fun levelDown(therapyPackage: TherapyPackage) {
    showMessage(getString(R.string.level_down, therapyPackage.title?.getText))
}
```

the same happens for levelUp. You should review what are you trying to achieve with this call and change either the declaration or calling sites of this properties/functions.